# JSF datatable populate rows based on selection

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I have two datatables in one jsf page and both are having two different managed beans.

```
//master table
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="req" lazy="true"
            value="#{emp.lazyModel}" paginator="true" rows="10"
            selection="#{emp.selectedRequest}">         
            <p:ajax event="rowSelectRadio" listener="#{emp.onRowSelect}" />
            <p:column selectionMode=">
                <h:outputText value="#{req.empNo}" />
            </p:column>



// detail table
<p:dataTable id="Det" var="det" lazy="true"
            value="#{dept.lazyModel}" paginator="true" rows="1">

            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="DeptNo" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{det.deptNo}" />
            </p:column>
```

Managed beans respectively

// Master table managed Bean

```
@Named("emp")
@ViewAccessScoped
public class EmployeeManagedBean implements Serializable {

@PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        initTable();
    }
```

// Detail table managed Bean

```
@Named("dept")
@ViewAccessScoped
public class DepartmentManagedBean implements Serializable {

@PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        initTable();
    }
```

`initTable()` is a method which populates LazyModel for both managed beans

When I select a row in master datatable, I am able to get selected row value in managed bean for first datatable which is `EmployeeManagedBean`

My question is what is the best approach to populate the second datatable by passing the selected row value of first datatable to second managed bean and thus populate the second datatable?  The triggering point to display values in second datable should be based on the selection of a row in first datatable.

Any help is highly appreciable.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am new with this all, but I try doing like this:

1. pass selected row to second bean (DepartmentManagedBean)
2. took departments according to selected row
3. update second datatable, using p:ajax attribute *update*

Comment: Darka, your answer especially point no 3 almost solved my problems. Some work still remains, then I could confirm whether my form is working or not. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot, my master-detail form is working, still some tweaking needs to be done. Appreciated.

Comment: Great that I could help :)